# EWS create an appointment in Outlook Calendar but also created the appointment in Deleted Items folder

Tags: vb.net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am using VB.Net and EWS Managed API to create appointments in Exchange 2010.  When i call the "Save" method, an appointment is also created in the "Deleted Items" folder in the Outlook.  Why is it the appointment is created in the "Deleted Items" folder? How do i avoid the appointment created in the "Deleted Items" folder? Thanks.

I use below code to save an appointment in the Outlook Calendar:

> appointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy)

Comment: Nobody has any idea? Or do not understand my question?

Comment: I don't think the "Save" method is placing an email in the deleted folder. What will place an email in the deleted folder is accepting a calendar invite. Do you have further code samples of what you are doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the cause of it.  There is an option in Outlook "Delete meeting requests and responses that have been updated".

When I unchecked this option, the appointment created will not appear in the "Deleted Items" folder.

I think it is also related to the AutomateProcessing of the Exchange, I guess EWS as the default of AutoUpdate.